# Profiling an application with Redis and getting ObjectNative::WaitTimeout

Tags: redis, profiling, stackexchange.redis

I am profiling an application which gives timeouts when there are cache misses. In my code I am doing batching, so basically I send multiple batches (size = 100) in parallel to fetch data from Redis. These requests are in parallel and I know that if I send a single batch of 200 it will not timeout, so Ideally multiple batches of 100 should not timeout.

But I do see timeout, and profiling the application I see that about 68 percent of the time is spent in this code.

ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl    670 ms
   OTHER ObjectNative::WaitTimeout   648 ms 
   BLOCKING

Can someone give some insights into what this means.. does this mean there is queuing happening or how to figure out where the issue might be.  Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more info. Code, profiling results. timeout settings, actual time spent, etc.